# How do I forward declare HANDLE? (Win32)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How do I forward declare `HANDLE`? I don't want to include all of `windows.h` in this particular header.

Comment: Isn't `#define HANDLE int` not enough?

Comment: @ruslik: HANDLE is not an `int`. In particular, I believe it is the same width as a pointer.

Comment: @Billy actually it's an index into some tables in kernel space. And anyway, you don't need to perform any arithmetics on it.

Comment: Is this performance critical code?  Or would wrapping `HANDLE` using pimpl be an option?  Because that's a whole lot cleaner than trying to forward declare an opaque type from the Windows API.

Comment: @Ruslik: Not always. Things like window handles are not kernel related at all. @James: It's not exactly performance critical but it seems a waste to include that massive header just to have HANDLE exposed. I thought it was just a `void *` but I'm curious if there's an accepted way of doing this.

Comment: @Billy:  In a 32-bit project, it is just a `void*`; I don't know whether it's a `void*` when building for Intel 64 or IA-64 (and I can't find out, my 64-bit workstation having died this morning).  While it's unlikely due to backwards compatibility that the underlying type would change in the future, it's not really a good practice to assume a given implementation of an opaque type.

Comment: @Billy: but a Window handle is an HWND, not a HANDLE. The two types might (sometimes sort of) happen to coincide, but definitely should not be treated as equivalent.

Comment: @Jerry: My point is that HANDLE is used in many places, not always in reference to the Kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header that actually typedefs `HANDLE` is `winnt.h`.  Unfortunately this is 15K lines - here, so fixing your issue by including the slimline `windef.h` is a bit misleading.

Here is the relevant part on my system (obviously the details could change from revision to revision, but won't change at the implementation level since this would break existing binaries):

```
//
// Handle to an Object
//

#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
#else
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif
typedef HANDLE *PHANDLE;
```

PS gotta love that `#if 0` in this shipping Microsoft header file.

Answer (score 3):

Well, looks like I answered this one myself. I just `#include`ed `<windef.h>` instead of `<windows.h>` for now. I would still like to be able to forward declare just HANDLE if anyone has a way of doing so.

Comment: I did the same, but I get a plethora of compiler errors from `winnt.h`. Any idea why?